# What is an "Invalid Request" for Discord?

Tags: discord, discord.py

Recently, my bot got temporarily banned because it exceeded 10000 invalid requests in under 10 minutes. One of the support workers explained that it causes your bot to be banned temporarily for 1 hour. He said that I should make future pre-cautions on how to limit my invalid requests. Upon asking what exactly an invalid request is and an example of one, he just didn't respond.

What exactly is an "invalid request" and an example of one. I can't really prevent any new invalid requests if I don't know what they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about this in the Discord docs here: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits#invalid-request-limit

As it reads, invalid requests are requests that return 401, 403, or 429 error codes. While I don't entirely understand what these are, I can guess that 401 codes are caused by bad bot tokens, 403 codes are caused by doing tasks your bot doesn't have the permissions to do, and 429 codes are caused by simply having too many requests.

A way to fix this is to refactor your code into countering these invalid requests. A way you could do this is to have a way to process, for example, users using commands they don't have permission to, your bot not having permission to use commands, cooldowns on your commands, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by too many requests? Like commands being processed?

Comment: @goos.mp4 that means that your bot send too many HTTP requests to the discord server, i.e. more than 10 000 in 10 minutes. You should monitor your bot and throttle your request rate if it comes close to around 16/17 request per second.

Comment: @goose.mp4 That's what I'm guessing. Again, I don't entirely understand this, but that makes the most sense.

Comment: @Jozott what exactly classifies as an HTTP request?

Comment: @goose.mp4 HTTP is the protocol your bot uses to communicate with the discord server,to retrieve or send data. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP

It is used for every website you view through the browser.

Comment: @goose.mp4, are you using discord.js for your bot?

Comment: @goose.mp4 Any request your bot makes to Discord at all is an HTTP request

Comment: @Jozott The post is tagged discord.py, so he is probably using discord.py

Comment: So, how exactly should I approach this situation? Add code to prevent it flagging and invalid request/error? For example maybe, add cooldowns to command, make it so if an user enters a command that doesn't exist it doesn't send an invalid request, make sure if the bot doesn't have permission to command it doesn't send an invalid request, etc; or do I have the wrong idea here.

Comment: @goose.mp4 I think you should rethink your code. You probably have some unnecessary requests you could refactor. But yeah, your suggested approaches are correct. You could implement a counter that stores how many requests have been sent in the last few minutes, and if the number is too high, the command is aborted.

Comment: @Jozott Alright, thank you. Helped alot and resolved the problem. Aswell as airD

Comment: @goose.mp4 No problem